# How to print all text file with winapi c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I try to print a text file, but printer print only one line
My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>

 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
 {
     PRINTDLG prDlg;
     memset(&prDlg, 0, sizeof(prDlg));
     prDlg.lStructSize = sizeof(prDlg);
     prDlg.Flags = PD_RETURNDC;

     if (!PrintDlg(&prDlg))
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, "PrintDlg(&pd) failed!", "Fatal Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
         return -1;
     }

     HDC hPrinter = prDlg.hDC;

     DOCINFO document_Information;
     memset(&document_Information, 0, sizeof(document_Information));
     document_Information.cbSize = sizeof(document_Information);
     StartDoc(hPrinter, &document_Information);

     StartPage(hPrinter);

     std::string filePath = "D:/documents/text.txt"; 

     std::ifstream file(filePath);
     if (file.is_open())
     {
         std::string line;
         std:: string content;
         int y = 100;
         while (std::getline(file, line))
         {
             line += "\r\n";
             TextOutA(hPrinter, 100, y, line.c_str(), line.length());
             y += 50;
             //TextOutA(hPrinter, 100, 120, "\n", 1); // Додаємо перенос рядка
         }
         file.close();
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to open the file!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
     }

     EndPage(hPrinter);

     EndDoc(hPrinter);
     DeleteDC(hPrinter);

     return 0;
 }
```

I read a lot of articles, but I did not find a solution, or I am omitting something important.
Maybe you know how to solve this problem

Comment: It seems the loop `while (std::getline...` exists after first iteration. Have you examined this?

Comment: You never check for any errors in your API calls.

Comment: I can recommend to use `CreateFile` and other Win32 API for file I/O instead of C++ `std::`.

Comment: Why not simply [`ShellExecuteA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) with a `"print"` operation? What is your actual and original assignment or exercise? What are your requirements and limitations?

Comment: Does *test.txt* contain more than a single line of text?

Comment: If the file contains more than 1 line, what kind of line breaks does it use? CR, LF, or CRLF? On Windows, the customary line break is CRLF, but `std::getline()` will handle both LF and CRLF equally, but not recognize CR at all